# html_entity_decode bug in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to clear parsed text with convert HTML entities to their literal character equivalent.

For example:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
$data = file_get_contents($url);

echo json_encode(array('data' => array('fulltext' => clear($mt[1]) )));

function clear($s) {
$s = trim($s);
$s = preg_replace('#<a(.*?)>(.*?)</a>#', "\$2", $s);
$s = strip_tags($s);
$s = html_entity_decode($s);
echo $s;
return $s;
}
```

This code returns `{"data":{"fulltext":null}}`, but echo (in this code it's for debug) works correct. If I comment line with html_entity_decode code works correct at all.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is in `$mt[1]` ?

Comment: The problem is likely to be before that. `json_encode()` requires all incoming characters to be valid UTF-8 characters, else it will return an empty string